# Laravel - When using make:migration created tables in database generates empty migration file

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb, laravel-migrations, laravel-6.2

I`m running a new installation of Laravel, with clean database and files.

I created a table named "frooth" and it has the columns id, title and created_at (id PK, varchar and datetime)

When I run "php artisan make:migration frooth" command, the created migration file is empty, only containing the up() and down() functions and nothing more (no columns)

How can I solve this, I followed the basic configuration of the framework as documented in official website, I can access and create functions in artisan as expected, only migrations its not working.

I generated the project with the command:  composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog

```sql
create table laravel.frooth
(
    id         int auto_increment
        primary key,
    title      varchar(250) null,
    created_at datetime     null
);
```

The PHP class generated in database/migrations/2019_10_25_012925_frooth.php:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class Frooth extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Console output:

```sh
php artisan make:migration frooth
Created Migration: 2019_10_25_012925_frooth
```

Comment: Don't create your table manually. Use your migration file to make the table. After you add your columns to the migration table, save the file and run: `php artisan migrate` 

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#generating-migrations

Comment: When you have an existing database and want to make a new laravel project for it, you could use https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator to generate the needed migration files

Comment: @JulianStark, unfortunately the Xethron/migrations-generator is incompatible with this version of Laravel, but I will test the others versions of Laravel package.

Comment: @echo In this case, I was considering to use Laravel Voyager in this project (which creates databases from its admin interface, and not creating every database in source code. But I will look forward to test that too.

Answer (score 0):

Delete that table you made manually and delete that migration file.

Run `php artisan make:migration create_frooths_table`

Then add your columns to the new migration file.

Something similar to this:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class Frooth extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('frooths', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
          }); 
        }
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('frooths');
    }
}
```

Then run `php artisan migrate`

For the `id` you might need to use `$table->bigIncrements('id');` if using Laravel 6